# Creating a Form class doesnt work in Symfony, shows no error

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony

I am trying to create a simple form in `Symfony` from a form class. The code shows no error but it is not displayed in the browser. Anybody has any idea what am I doing wrong?

Controller

```
namespace ReuseBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use ReuseBundle\Entity\Company;
use ReuseBundle\ReuseForms\CreateCompany;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{
public function newAction()
{
    $company = new Company();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CreateCompany(),$company, array(
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl('reuse_create'),
        'method'=>'POST'

    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label'=>'Create Company'));
    return $this->render('ReuseBundle:Default:create.html.twig', array(
        'form'=>$form->createView()
    ));
}

public function createAction(Request $request)
{

}
}
```

Form Class

```
<?php

namespace ReuseBundle\ReuseForms;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class CreateCompany extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForms(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array    $options){
        $builder
            ->add('Company_Name')
        ->add('address')
        ->add('Zip')
        ->add('City')
        ->add('Country')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('fax')
        ->add('com_email', 'email')
        ->add('website');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'ReuseBundle_Company';
}
}
```

The entity where i generated the get and set methods with doctrine

```
namespace ReuseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table{name="Company"}
 */
class Company{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=250)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=2)
 */
protected $Company_name;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=300)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=15)
 *
 */
protected $address;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer",length=7)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=3)
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
 */
protected $Zip;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $City;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $Country;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $phone;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=25)
 */
protected $fax;
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $com_email;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $website;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set Company_name
 *
 * @param string $companyName
 * @return Company
 */
public function setCompanyName($companyName)
{
    $this->Company_name = $companyName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Company_name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCompanyName()
{
    return $this->Company_name;
}

/**
 * Set address
 *
 * @param string $address
 * @return Company
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get address
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * Set Zip
 *
 * @param integer $zip
 * @return Company
 */
public function setZip($zip)
{
    $this->Zip = $zip;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Zip
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getZip()
{
    return $this->Zip;
}

/**
 * Set City
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return Company
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->City = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get City
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->City;
}

/**
 * Set Country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return Company
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->Country = $country;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Country
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->Country;
}

/**
 * Set phone
 *
 * @param string $phone
 * @return Company
 */
public function setPhone($phone)
{
    $this->phone = $phone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPhone()
{
    return $this->phone;
}

/**
 * Set fax
 *
 * @param string $fax
 * @return Company
 */
public function setFax($fax)
{
    $this->fax = $fax;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fax
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getFax()
{
    return $this->fax;
}

/**
 * Set website
 *
 * @param string $website
 * @return Company
 */
public function setWebsite($website)
{
    $this->website = $website;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get website
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getWebsite()
{
    return $this->website;
}
}
```

html.twig

## Create Company

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

routing
    reuse_company:
    path: /new
    defaults: {_controller : ReuseBundle:Company:new}

```
reuse_create:
    path:      /create
    defaults: { _controller: ReuseBundle:Company:create}
    requirements: { _method: post }
```

Comment: If you just display a static html instead of a form, is it working? I.e. you see the page?

Answer (score 0):

Because you must invoke Form::handleRequest() and Form::isValid() in action controller method, just like this:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CreateCompany(),$company, array(
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl('reuse_create'),
        'method'=>'POST'

    ));
    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label'=>'Create Company'));
    # Must have
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // the validation passed, do something with the $company object        
    }
    # Show empty form or form with errors (if any)
    return $this->render('ReuseBundle:Default:create.html.twig', array(
        'form'=>$form->createView()
    ));
}
```

When invoking Form:handleRequest() object is validated. handleRequest()writes inputed data back into the $company object.f it is invalid (validation is covered in the next section), isValid() returns false again, so the form is rendered together with all validation errors;

Comment: But the form handleRequest and Form is valid are after the form is created... The form is not displayed...

Answer (score 0):

In your form class definition, the name of the method must be **buildForm** and not **buildForms**:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
```

Comment: makes no change at all still my form isnt displayed